# Creating array from multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array where users enters multiple items into text box. All i can get my function to return is the first entry. Maybe i am approaching this wrong?

```js
function treez() {
  var treesArray = [];
  var ar = treesArray.push(document.getElementById("trees").value);
  var st = treesArray.toString();
  document.getElementById("tresult").innerHTML = st;

}
```

```html
Enter 7 Trees
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="trees" name "trees"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="treez()">submit</button>
<br>
<p id="tresult">
  <p>
```

Comment: How can you enter multiple items through single text box??

Comment: I have the same doubt. If you want to do it with only one textarea or textbox, first you need to define which is your word separator, it can be a comma or just spaces (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Move `treesArray` out of the `trees` function.

With it being in there, its being recreated every call.

```js
var treesArray = [];
function treez() {
  var ar = treesArray.push(document.getElementById("trees").value);
  var st = treesArray.toString();
  document.getElementById("tresult").innerHTML = st;
}
```

```html
Enter 7 Trees
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="trees" name "trees"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" class="processButton" onclick="treez()">submit</button>
<br>
<p id="tresult">
  <p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, asking the user to separate each entry with a comma:

```
var treesArray = []
function treez() {
    var trees = document.getElementById("trees").value;
    treesArray = trees.split(",");
    document.getElementByID("tresult").innerHTML = treesArray + 
       "   " +  treesArray.join(" - ");
}
```